# Add v-model to inputs in nested v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

Let's say I have component like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="n in 2" :key="n">
      <div v-for="i in 2" :key="i">
        <input type="number" v-model="foo[n][i]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ foo }} </pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

This render 4 inputs. Now when I enter something into this inputs for example 1 to 4 to each I would like `foo` to become:

```js
[
    [1,2],
    [3,4]
]
```

instead I have an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: Hi, the problem here is that `foo` variable has no definition, when you create `foo[n][i]` -> `foo[n]`(undefined)`[i]` which means you'll have a typeError. i suggest to set a default value to `foo` or create a `method` to initiate the `foo` variable with all values then go for `v-for` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is from the fact that the `n` and `i` indexes start at 1 in the `v-for`

Also for a more generic approach you could generate an array from the dimensions in your `created` lifecycle.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    array: []
  },
  created() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.y; i++) {
      let row = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.x; j++) {
        row.push(0);
      }
      this.array.push(row);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="n in y" :key="n" style="display:flex">
    <div v-for="i in x" :key="i">
      <input type="number" v-model.number="array[n - 1][i - 1]">
    </div>
  </div>
  {{array}}
</div>
```

Comment: No I still have same error unless I generate array in `created` which shouldn't be required I think? Take a look at HelloWorld.vue in https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-tzlnn

Comment: In other words - is it required to generate array dummy in created hook to make it work?

Comment: It's nor required. May check https://codepen.io/Govorun/pen/pooaPNL?editors=1010

Comment: Yeh but I don't know how many inputs I'll have so I can not just fill it with static data

Comment: So basically I need to create array skeleton I think.

Comment: Yes in your codesandbox the array is empty this cannot work. You either need an array skeleton or construct the array just like in my example

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution: by adding a method to initial new object if it's `undefined`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="n in 2" :key="n">
            <div v-for="i in 2" :key="i">
                <input type="number" v-model="getfoo(n)[i]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <pre>{{ foo }} </pre>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
methods: {
    getfoo(n) {
        if(!this.foo[n]) this.foo[n] = {}; // or = [] 
        return this.foo[n];
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you for effort but I think this make even more mess. I'll just create this array skeleton with empty arrays so v-model will work correctly

Comment: yeah, after all this method helps you if you're not using a initial value/dump :)